# GCC version versus basic string

Tags: c++, string, debugging

I'm running a .cpp code where I get some string dependence error 
     "basic_string.tcc: No such file or directory"

which should come from some compatibility issue. On my MAC machine "clang version 11.0.0" it works but on my linux machine with gcc 6.3.0 its fails. This happens on function

```
line read_in(std::string filename_begin, std::string fileformat, size_type n_files)
```

Any idea how to debug this perhaps,

thanks, Damir

Comment: I hope you mean `gcc` in the general sense but are actually using `g++` to compile.

Comment: It looks like your compiler installation on Linux is broken.

Comment: Correct running with g++ -std=c++11...;

Comment: If you try to compile `#include <string> #include <iostream> int main() { std::string test = "test"; std::cout << test; }` does that work on your Linux machine?

Comment: yes this is fine;

Comment: To use `std::string` you need to `#include <string>`

Comment: Works on my machine.  Can you provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem (along the lines of what Nathan had you try), and include the command line you are using to compile.  I suspect the bug is in the code not provided.